# Autowidth property not working on datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am adding columns to a datatable which has the `autoWidth` property set to `true`. But the columns I add are much narrower than the original ones.
Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/e2t3kvke/2/)

Here is what the result looks like :
[image]

`a` and `b` are the original columns while `test0..3` are added.
I would like that all columns auto-adjust to their respective content sizes.

All help welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables unfortunatly doesn't support adding columns, so a hack is needed to get the required functionality.

In your fiddle you save the current width of the columns when you do this;

```
cols = theDT.settings()[0].aoColumns;
```

So we need to reset this saved width with this code (add it just before recreating the table inside the addColumnToDataTable function)

```
for (var k=0;k<cols.length;k++){
  cols[k]['sWidth'] = (100/(cols.length)) + '%';
  cols[k]['sWidthOrig'] = (100/(cols.length)) + '%';
}
```

Comment: so if within `aoColumns` I only copy `data` and `title` for each column it would automatically recalc for me ?

Comment: Then you would basically be recreating the entire table, so that should work as well.

Comment: yep that s what I did in the end rather than relying on manual width calculation. I'll still validate your answer since it pointed me in the right direction. cheers.